# Simple Data picker meta box

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-field, wp-admin, metabox

Hello everybody I tried to follow many post and guides but with results not according to my needs. I need a simple meta box that catches a data timestamp like the standard one in Wordpress posts or pages. I've created a metabox but the

```
type="date"
```

attribute to HTML form prints a datepicker in english format and I need to translate it in italian. The standard date picker from Wordpress is allready translated in Italian... I don't want to install a plugin because I've created a plugin for custom post type on my own and I'm updating the code with these new functionalities. I'm going to paste my code below. Thanks , in advance.

```
<?php 

function arrivo_meta_box_markup($object)
{
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");

    ?>
        <div>
            <label for="arrivo_meta_box">Data arrivo in negozio</label>
            <input name="arrivo_meta_box" type="date" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, "arrivo_meta_box", true); ?>">
        </div>
    <?php  
}
```

Comment: The output of `type="date"` is handled by the browser, as it's a native control. So it should reflect the user's browser language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ones was answering so i installed this plugin [MetaBox.io](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/)

and I've generated this code below that worsk very vell.

```
function arrivo_metabox( $meta_boxes ) {
  $prefix = 'arrivo-';

  $meta_boxes[] = array(
    'id' => 'arrivo',
    'title' => esc_html__( 'Data di arrivo in negozio', 'porto-child' ),
    'post_types' => array( 'riparazioni' ),
    'context' => 'side',
    'priority' => 'default',
    'autosave' => false,
    'fields' => array(
      array(
        'id' => $prefix . 'data_arrivo',
        'type' => 'date',
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Data arrivo in negozio', 'porto-child' ),
        'js_options' => array(
          'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/yy',
          'dayNames' => '[ "Domenica", "Lunedì "Martedi", "Mercoledì", "Giovedì", "Venerdì", "Sabato" ]',
        ),
        'class' => 'data-arrivo',
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $meta_boxes;
}
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'arrivo_metabox' );
```